# Bash - mv directories from subdirectory to parent

Tags: bash, mv

I have directory `~/Desktop/Projects`. Within that are 40 subdirectories, let's call them `AAA, BBB, CCC, etc`. Within each of those are 4 identical directories `dog, fish, bird, snake`. And within each of those are 2000 files each. I want to move the discretely named files from `Projects/AAA/dog, fish, bird, snake` into `AAA`, then continue to `BBB` and its own respective `BBB/dog, fish, bird, snake` files into `BBB` an on through all 40 subdirectories.

I read that I should save a shell script in a `bin` folder within the path. I am very new, with no instruction, only what I find online. I created a `bin` directory -- `~/Desktop/bin`. I can't change the `.bashrc` because I am a student. (And, yes, I probably *could* but shouldn't.) This is one version of the code that I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd ~/Desktop/Projects

for d in ~Desktop/Projects; do
    cd dog ;
    mv * .. ;
done
```

I added, but commented out for now, the other 3 subdirs. When I run this it sends all of the `AAA, BBB, CCC, etc` directories to `~/Desktop`. I thought the `..` code only sent files to the directory enclosing the one it was in?

I thought that I was essentially saying "for all directories (`AAA, BBB, CCC, etc`) in `Projects` cd to its enclosed `dog` directory, then move the contents to the respective parent of the `dog` directory". Which is what I want.

I have also tried `for d in ~Desktop/Projects/*/ ; do` in which case it can't find the `dog` directory.

I have also tried `for d in */ ; do`, and `for d in /* ; do`, and `for dir in */ ; do` same problem, can't find `dog`.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `for` loop sets `d` to `~/Desktop/Projects`. It loops only once. You then perform a `cd dog`. This fails, becauce your current directory is `~/Desktop/Projects` and has no subdirectory `dog`. Your intention seems to be looping through AAA, BBB etc. This is done like this: `for d in AAA BBB CCC` or, if you want to loop through all Projects directories, `for d in *`. In the loop body, `cd $d/dog`, then the `mv`, then go back up `cd ../..`. Do yourself a favour and test this on a **copy** of your data.

Comment: How do you want to handle potential name collisions where e.g. a file in `snake` has the same name as a file in `dog`?

Comment: @berndbausch - I guess some of my confusion is that I read that I couldn't use `cd` in a bash script, so I was looking for an alternative. Although I will try this, and yes, I've been using a duplicate body of data. @Kusalananda - as I said, each file is discretely named. Each filename includes the name of the parent folder, the subfolder and the "animal". This is just an example, of course, it is not animals.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem using `cd` in a shell script. The only caveat, perhaps: In your script, you must take care to go back to the original directory (i.e., `~/Desktop/Projects`) after you have moved the files. It is a common error to cd somewhere, then forget to go back.

Comment: The script is contained in the sample `/Projects` file. I used `for  d  in  * ` because, yes, there are 40 directories I ultimately want to run this on within `/Projects`.  I used  `cd $d/dog`. I tried the script on 4 sample AAA-level directories within a sample `/Projects` directory. It seemed to hang for a full minute, then returned an error that the BBB directory did not exist. Nothing else changed. I do have a `set -e` within the script because in previous iterations it attempted to mv folders from the home directory.

Comment: @berndbausch Because of the "no such file or directory", I then removed all but one sample AAA-level folder. I ran the script and got this error - mv: cannot stat '*' : No such file or directory.

Comment: The shell expands the asterisk in `for d in *` to the list of all files and directories in the current directory (except those whose names start with a dot). The latest error indicates that the current directory is empty, the asterisk is not expanded and remains an asterisk.

Comment: @berndbausch But there are 40 directories in the current directory.

Comment: My guess is that the script has a different current directory when it runs `for d in *`. It is easy to confirm that: Just use `pwd` (***p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory*) before you enter the `for` loop.